# Getting 504 Gateway Timeout error **Prerender.io**

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, prerender

> Getting **504 Gateway timeout** error on http://localhost:3000
>
> I have installed Prerender.io successfully in Windows 7 after running node 
>   server.js command the application is set message displays server is running 
>   [image]on port 3000 but when i access through browser i am getting 504 error

[phpMyAdmin Error 504 Gateway Timeout Reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270165/phpmyadmin-error-504-gateway-timeout-reloaded)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the Prerender server something to render. For example:

http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com/

Just going to the root returns a 504 because there is no URL being passed in.

Feel free to email me at todd@prerender.io if you need any help getting set up!

Comment: I have done what you told and have got the response where it dint consists of any images and for my angularjs application it is returning only variable instead of contents. The same i have mailed you